# Ubuntu-Unable to install Node JS Pulsar Client

Tags: node.js, ruby, canvas

I am trying to install Canvas on my Ubuntu 18.04. I have installed `Apache`, `NodeJS`, `Ruby`, `Yarn` successfully, and also additional packages required for `Canvas` as follows:

> sudo apt install python zlib1g-dev libxml2-dev libsqlite3-dev libpq-dev libxmlsec1-dev make g++ git-core

Used Git to download the Canvas repository:

> git clone https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms.git ~/canvas

Change into the repository directory and check out the latest stable branch of the repository:

> cd ~/canvas

> git checkout stable

Create a new directory for Canvas, copy the repository there, and change its ownership to the current user:

> sudo mkdir -p /var/canvas

> sudo cp -R ~/canvas /var

> sudo chown -R $USER /var/canvas

> cd /var/canvas

Used Bundle to install Canvas’s Ruby dependencies.

> bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'

> bundle install

Here comes my problem friend. The console guy suggested me to use the latest bundle which I did - `bundle _2.2.15_ install`.

After all the research I get the below error which I am not able to fix when I do - `npm install pulsar-client`.

```
npm WARN deprecated node-pre-gyp@0.15.0: Please upgrade to @mapbox/node-pre-gyp: the non-scoped node-pre-gyp package is deprecated and only the @mapbox scoped package will receive updates in the future
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> pulsar-client@1.3.0 install /var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-cpp/libpulsar-v1.3.0-node-v83-linux-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for pulsar-client@1.3.0 and node@14.17.0 (node-v83 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
make: Entering directory '/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build'
  CC(target) Release/obj.target/nothing/../node-addon-api/nothing.o
  AR(target) Release/obj.target/../node-addon-api/nothing.a
  COPY Release/nothing.a
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/Pulsar/src/addon.o
In file included from ../src/addon.cc:20:0:
../src/Message.h:24:10: fatal error: pulsar/c/message.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pulsar/c/message.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Pulsar.target.mk:124: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/Pulsar/src/addon.o' failed
make: *** [Release/obj.target/Pulsar/src/addon.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-142-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build/Release/libpulsar.node" "--module_name=libpulsar" "--module_path=/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build/Release/libpulsar.node --module_name=libpulsar --module_path=/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.15.0-142-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.15.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build/Release/libpulsar.node --module_name=libpulsar --module_path=/var/canvas/node_modules/pulsar-client/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pulsar-client@1.3.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pulsar-client@1.3.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/sach7411/.npm/_logs/2021-05-17T15_07_29_218Z-debug.log
```

When I do the - `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`, I get `Error: Cannot find module 'nopt'`

Could experts here, please help on this?

Answer (score 1):

you need install pulsar c++ client first:

https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-node/

and then `npm install pulsar-client`